# Seach.php is not working and not showing any results

Tags: php, mysql, forms, search, input

I'm trying to figue out how to make my search.php script work with mySQL.  I can't get the information to show up.  Not sure where the problem is.

PAGE 1:

```
<form action="search_result.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="reg" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

PAGE 2:

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="XXXXXXXXXXX";
$password="XXXXXXXXXXX";
$db_name="XXXXXXXXXXXX";
$tbl_name="reg_add";
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$record = $_POST['record']; // if coming from e.g. a form
$result=mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM reg_add WHERE reg='" . mysql_real_escape_string($record) . "'");


$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$first_name = $row['first_name'];
$last_name = $row['last_name'];
$reg = $row['reg'];
?>

<input  name="reg" value="<? echo "$record" ?>">

<input  name="first_name" value="<? echo "$first_name" ?>">

<input  name="last_name" value="<? echo "$last_name" ?>">
```

Comment: `$record` doesn't appear to be set when you use it in the query.  Check `$result` and if its false call `mysql_error()` to see what error occurred.

Comment: Make sure all XXXXXXXXXXXX match actual values

Comment: The first problem I spot is that you are using (soon to be deprecated) [`mysql_*` functions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). Either use `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You form is method GET and in your PHP you use this:

```
$record = $_POST['record']; // if coming from e.g. a form
```

How are you gonna get the POST['record'] if your form has the method GET?

I guess you should or change your form to:

```
method="POST"
```

or change your $record in php to:

```
$record = $_GET['record'];
```

Try this version:

You form:

```
    <form action="search_result.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="reg" id="reg" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

search_result.php :

```
<?php

$host       ="localhost";
$username   ="XXXXXXXXXXX";
$password   ="XXXXXXXXXXX";
$db_name    ="XXXXXXXXXXXX";
$tbl_name   ="reg_add";

/* Connect to MySQL database */
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("Error connecting to database");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("Error selecting database");

$error = '';

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {


    if (!empty($_POST['reg'])) {

        $record = $_POST['reg']; // if coming from e.g. a form

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reg_add WHERE reg='" . mysql_real_escape_string($record) . "'");
        $result = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if ($result != 0) {

            $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

            $first_name = $row['first_name'];
            $last_name = $row['last_name'];
            $reg = $row['reg'];

        } else {

            $error = 'No result have been found!';

        }

    } else {

        $error = 'You have not entered the search field, <a href="javascript:history.back(1)">Go back</a>.';

    }
}

if (!empty($error)) { echo $error; } 
?>


<input  name="reg" value="<? echo $record; ?>">

<input  name="first_name" value="<? echo $first_name; ?>">

<input  name="last_name" value="<? echo $last_name; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")
```

Not your problem, but no need for quotes around variables:

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($db_name);
```

You should set the variable `$record` somewhere:

```
$record = $_POST['record']; // if coming from e.g. a form
$result=mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM reg_add WHERE reg='" . mysql_real_escape_string($record) . "'");
```

This is just wrong:

```
$first_name=mysql_result($result,"first_name");
$last_name=mysql_result($result,"last_name");
$reg=mysql_result($result,"reg");
```

And should be:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$first_name = $row['first_name'];
$last_name = $row['last_name'];
$reg = $row['reg'];
```

Also: you shouldn't use [`mysql_*` functions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) anymore. Use either `mysqli_*` or PDO.

And remember that if something doesn't work you can check [`mysql_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to see any error doing a query.

Comment: Appreciate your help.  I updated my script above, but I still can't find a result.

Comment: @Paul Btw, I *do* agree that PDO in any case is a better API choice, but proclaiming prepared statements to be the solution to all escaping problems is wrong in my eyes. Especially considering that PDO by default emulates prepared statements using an escaping function which wasn't character set aware until recently (charset support was added in 5.3.6 I think and you have to explicitely specify it in the DSN). real_escape_string on the other hand *is* character set aware, if you set it correctly.

Comment: I updated my question with your corrections.  I still can't get a result.  I feel like I'm so close.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of mysql_result() is wrong. According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php), it should be

> string mysql_result ( resource $result , int $row [, mixed $field = 0 ] )

SO the correct way to use it would be like

```
mysql_result($result, 1, "first_name");
```